# Initialize tinymce on update after ajax with Rails 4

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am using the tinymce-rails gem which essentially just adds the jquery plugin.
Every thing works great until I render the page via ajax response.
I have tried re-initializing tinymce again, but it still does not work.

On my controller i have:

```
def update
  @topic = Topic.find params[:id]

  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

Then in my format.js which would be update.js i have.

```
$('#topic_list').html('<%= escape_javascript render('topic_list') %>');
tinymce.EditorManager.execCommand('mceRemoveEditor', false, "tiny_mce_id");
tinymce.EditorManager.execCommand('mceAddEditor', false, "tiny_mce_id");

tinyMCE.init({
selector: "textarea",
theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "top",
theme_advanced_toolbar_align: "left",
theme_advanced_statusbar_location: "bottom",
theme_advanced_buttons3_add: ["tablecontrols","fullscreen"],
plugins: "link,autolink,image,print,preview,charmap,code,emoticons,hr,legacyoutput,searchreplace,textcolor,placeholder",
file_browser_callback: "file_upload",
browser_spellcheck: true,
body_id: "tiny_mce_id",
toolbar: ["bold italic forecolor backcolor | alignleft aligncenter alignright | styleselect | link image | preview | charmap code emoticons searchreplace "],
menubar: false,
statusbar: false
});
```

And this does not work. When my topic_list gets rendered, I just have the textarea, but tinymce is not initialized.

Can some one direct me on what I need to do here to get tinymce to load again on an format.js for Rails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the Ajax response file, you can remove and init tinyMCE again.
So in response.js or in my case, update.js you need this code:

```
tinymce.remove();
tinimce.init({
  selector: "textarea"
  plugins: ...
  ...
});
```

This works perfect when rendering the page again with new comments on the page.
And if you want to edit the new or existing comment, tinymce will still work.

Hope this helps someone else that may be looking for the same question.